# Working VM in KVM, cannot mount volumes inside disk image, after graceful reboot of host

Tags: mount, kvm

So I have a Centos based VM (NethServer) inside a KVM host (UNRAID).
I have this for years and has proven very resilient, surviving host power cuts etc.

Today I rebooted the host gracefully, because of an update.
The update probably also upgraded KVM version (not sure from which version to whitch but I don't expect a dramatic change). Note that other VMs work fine.
VM's configuration wasn't touched.

After the reboot the VM does start, but cannot (AFAIK) mount any of the volumes inside the (raw) image. The file is in an M.2 that works fine.

This is what I see in the console:

[image]

Help me please, I have no clue what to do.

Comment: Are you sure that `VolGroup`, `lv_root`, and `lv_swap` are the correct names?

Comment: I think Centos initramfs includes the `lvm` tool. You could use it so see which PVs, VGs and LVs (if any) are available. I am not so sure if `lsblk` is included; if yes, it would provide a convenient overview of your block devices including LVM structures they might contain.

Comment: Of course, you could also use something like `guestfish` or `guestmount` to analyze the image file on the host.